# Change Image prototype

Tags: javascript

How does one augment `setAttribute` of Image? I did try few things but quickly ran into issues.

```js
  var originalSetAttribute = Image.prototype.setAttribute;

  Image.prototype.setAttribute = function (key, value) {
    console.log('set attribute', key, ' -> ', value);

    var val = (key === 'src') ? getCorrectSrc(value) : value;

    // first attempt
    originalSetAttribute(key, val);
    // second attempt
    Image.prototype.__proto__.setAttribute(key, val);
  };
```

I get **Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation**.

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/0hn9zyoc/)

---

Please no "this is bad practise" comments, sometimes in life you're in a situation where you have no choice but to hack your way through the worst possible situations because the specific IT area you work in is messed up and full of weird standards.

Besides, I'll put this logic into iframe, so that it doesn't mess up the top window Image.

**Goal:**

Third-party library adds images using the following APIs:

```js
var img = new Image; 
img.src = '..'; 
img.setAttribute('src', '..');
```

`src` values are inlined into their code but I need to use other `src` values. It's much easier to hack the Image compared to parsing their JS files and doing expensive and complex string searches and replacements.

Plus points if you can help me with Image `src` setter as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `.call` the original `setAttribute` function with the `this` that your patched `setAttribute` was called with:

```
return originalSetAttribute.call(this, key, val);
```

To patch the setter (and getter):

```
const { get, set } = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Image.prototype, 'src');
Object.defineProperty(Image.prototype, 'src', {
  set(newVal) {
    return set.call(this, getCorrectSrc(newVal));
  },
  get() {
    return get.call(this);
  }
});
```